# Routing specs fails because hashes are stored differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

My test example is:

```
it "routes to #add_role" do
  post("/users/1/add_role").should route_to("users#add_role",id: 1)
end
```

Here is the failure message:

```
UsersController routing routes to #add_role
     Failure/Error: post("/users/1/add_role").should route_to("users#add_role",id: 1)
       The recognized options <{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add_role", "id"=>"1"}> did not match <{"id"=>1, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add_role"}>, difference: <{"id"=>1}>.
       <{"id"=>1, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add_role"}> expected but was
       <{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add_role", "id"=>"1"}>.
```

My environment:

- ruby-1.9.3-p194
- Rails 3.2.6
- Rspec (2.10.0)

Comment: Param values are passed as strings. Use `route_to("users#add_role", id: "1")`

Answer (score -2):

You need id in the route_to to be string.
Rails does not type cast into numbers as it makes no assumptions about types